# Add an element to DIV based on condition

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to insert a `<table>` element inside a `<div>` at a particular location based on two conditions.

condition 1 : based on the page Num

condition 2 : based on the ordernum.

For example :

```
 <div id="printContainer">
      <table class="BKG pg1" id="tbl-09-338785" data-ordernum="0">
      </table>
      <table class="BKG pg1" id="tbl-09-338786" data-ordernum="1">
      </table>
      <table class="BKG pg2" id="tbl-09-338787" data-ordernum="0">
       </table>
      <table class="BKG pg2" id="tbl-09-338788" data-ordernum="1">  
      </table>
      <table class="BKG pg3" id="tbl-09-338789" data-ordernum="0">
      </table>
    </div>
```

If I want to enter

```
<table class="BKG pg2" id="tbl-09-338790" data-ordernum="5">
```

inside the `div` then it should get append to the list in between

```
<table class="BKG pg2" id="tbl-09-338788" data-ordernum="1">  and 
<table class="BKG pg3" id="tbl-09-338789" data-ordernum="0">
```

Now if I want to enter

```
<table class="BKG pg2" id="tbl-09-338791" data-ordernum="3">
```

inside the `div` then it should get append to the list in between

```
<table class="BKG pg2" id="tbl-09-338788" data-ordernum="1">  and 
<table class="BKG pg2" id="tbl-09-338790" data-ordernum="5">
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jNDRN/1)

Comment: Where are the `</table>` tags? and I am confused by the term _append between_; does append 790 between 788 and 789 means 788,789,790? or 788,790,789?

Comment: It should be 788,790,789

Comment: I've deleted my answer. A downvote for making a stab at a poor question is pretty tragic. +1 Timur. +1 mshsayem. "Append between" is an oxymoron.

Comment: While "append between" may be oxymoronic, it's not difficult to understand. He wishes to 'append' (add would be the proper word, I believe) the element to the list between two existing elements _or_ append it if it would not go between two existing elements.

Comment: the oxymoron wasn't what confused me, it just added to the folly of the question...but congratulations for understanding it better than we did.

Comment: Some people don't write English very well. Some write well but can't communicate well technically. Some people are mentally disorganized, and some people are just lazy and expect you to fill in the holes yourself. Hard to say what's going on here. I don't think lazy, because it's very well formatted and organized. Glad he got an answer.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English skills. English is not my first language. I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size: http://jsfiddle.net/S4yhS/

The work is handled by an `insert` function:

```
function insert(page, id, ordernum) {
    var didInsert = false;
    var table = $("<table>", {
        'class': "BKG pg" + String(page),
        'id': id,
        'data-ordernum': ordernum
    });

    $(".pg" + String(page)).each(function (idx, element) {
        if ($(element).data("ordernum") > ordernum) {
            $(element).before(table);
            didInsert = true;
        }
    });

    if (!didInsert) {
        $(".pg" + String(page)).last().after(table);
    }
}
```

It works like so:

1. Loop over each table on a page. These tables are assumed to already be ordered by `ordernum`
2. If the order number is greater than the given value, insert the given table before it.
3. If no greater order number exists, insert the given table at the end of the page.

Note that this was done using [jQuery](http://jquery.com). You can do the same without it, but it is more difficult. The basic methodology would remain the same, however.

Note also that using `String()` on the `page` value is not strictly necessary, but I like to explicitly typecast rather than let the language do it for me.

Test:

```
insert(2, "tbl-09-338790", 5);
insert(2, "tbl-09-338791", 3);
```

Results:

```
<div id="printContainer">
    <table class="BKG pg1" id="tbl-09-338785" data-ordernum="0"></table>
    <table class="BKG pg1" id="tbl-09-338786" data-ordernum="1"></table>
    <table class="BKG pg2" id="tbl-09-338787" data-ordernum="0"></table>
    <table class="BKG pg2" id="tbl-09-338788" data-ordernum="1"></table><table class="BKG pg2" id="tbl-09-338791" data-ordernum="3"></table><table class="BKG pg2" id="tbl-09-338790" data-ordernum="5"></table>
    <table class="BKG pg3" id="tbl-09-338789" data-ordernum="0"></table>
</div>
```

(Note: before and after don't add line breaks, but the display ought to be identical)

See also: [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) and [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/)